# create application for Mac OS X from ios

Tags: iphone, macos, cocos2d-iphone, gamekit

I have iPad game application. Now I want it for the Mac OS x. This application is using Cocos2D and Gamekit framework. How can I create Mac OS X application. Gamekit framework is only available in ios. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Yes, Actually when I create cocos2d Mac application and going to add gamekit framework it does not contain gamekit framework in the list of framework. Please help.

Comment: @Jason Boyle I think [Game Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is meant here, which is indeed only available on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a very broad question. You are asking how too create a Mac App which can't be done in a single SO answer

Your best start would be to use the Cocoa Application template and work forward. The Google and Apple example code will show you many examples.

Depending on how much of your program is rooted in the UIKit based API will determine how easy it is to translate your program. The UIKit framework doesnt exist in Mac but most items have an equivalent NSThing equivalent (UIButton is similar to NSButton)

You will have to disable the GameKit stuff as that isn't on MacOS(yet)

The core of your troubles will be to place your Cocos2D view into a NSWindow hierarchy and possibly full screen it at launch.

Good Luck

Comment: Yeah I would expect Game Kit on Mac OS soon though so I suggest you keep it in the app, just comment it out.